# What is the hotkey to scale up In Chrome Devtools Inspect Element when device mode is toggled to mobile?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When using Chrome dev tools and inspecting an element we have the option to toggle device mode. When we are viewing a mobile device in the top right corner there is a 'Scale Up' plus button. In the image below I'm referring to the plus sign on the right of the 1.2.

What is the hotkey or shortcut key for this button instead of pressing the plus sign?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + Scroll</kbd>

If we press and hold ctrl key and scroll with the mouse wheel this will zoom in and works well. This is the best hotkey I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Press the following

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>-</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>+</kbd>